# minitoc and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, minitoc

I want to create a document with table of contents for the main part and the appendix and hyperrefs for the generated pdf. My attempt so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{minitoc}

% Make the "Part I" text invisible
\renewcommand \thepart{}
\renewcommand \partname{}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
cover sheet
\end{titlepage}

\doparttoc
\faketableofcontents
\part{}
\parttoc
\newpage

\section{Section 1}
\newpage
\section{Section 2}
\newpage
\section{Section 3}
\newpage
\section{Section 4}
\newpage


\newpage


\begin{titlepage}
appendix
\end{titlepage}

\appendix
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\part{Appendix}
\parttoc
\newpage

\section{Appendix 1}
\newpage
\section{Appendix 2}

\end{document}
```

I have trouble with the following aspects:

- The language of the document is German, how can the table of contents be renamed? ("Table of contents" -> "Inhaltsverzeichnis")
- The hyperrefs in the PDF are messed up because of the included part for the minitoc. The sections should be at the first level, the appendix is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty top-level bookmarks entry is caused by `\part{}`. The bookmark for this "fake" entry can be disabled by:

```
\hypersetup{bookmarkstype=none}
\part{}
\hypersetup{bookmarkstype=toc}
```

The German part is easy, the traditional table of contents is covered by

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

And the language option can be given to `minitoc` for its names:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{minitoc}
```

Comment: Thanks, both issues are solved. If i use German translation, the word part / "Teil" before the table of contents is not hidden. In my example I used two commands to hide it, but it only works in English. Do you know a solution for this, too?

Comment: @CGX106: Either redefine it locally or use `\addto{\captionsngerman}{\renewcommand*{\partname}{}}`, if `babel` is loaded.